# I have VS2010 Ultimate. Shouldn't TFS Server be included?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Dumb question I'm sure, but when I log onto my MSDN subscription account, I don't see Team Foundation Server in the list of available for download software application. I thought it was supposed to come with VS2010 Ultimate, which I could download.

Is it a separate download? Could it be that my MSDN account level gives me access to VS2010 but that I am still not entitled to TFS?

I'd like to install it instead of using VSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/subscriptionschart.aspx), all of the "Visual Studio 2010  With MSDN" come with TFS Server 2010 as well.  On my account, the download was under Developer Tools -> Visual Studio 2010, and named *Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010 (x86 and x64) - DVD (English)*

Comment: Son of a gun, you are correct. I either expected TFS to be part of the installation of VS2010 or more likely, a separate download in a separate section of MSDN, not with the VS2010 download group. I expected that the download groups were just for various versions of 2010. I consider TFS a separate but related production. Thank, you!

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2010 should be available to you as a separate download if you have access to Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. According to this blog posting, MSDN gives you an unlimited test license and a license for a single production use server:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2009/10/20/tfs-2010-server-licensing-it-s-included-in-msdn-subscriptions.aspx

Also, according to the [VS 2010 licensing whitepaper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/B/1/7B18407A-AC79-4949-A318-A6636D96F497/Visual%20Studio%202010%20Licensing%20-%20Feb-2010.pdf) (which includes licensing details for TFS 2010), clients using VS 2010 Professional or better have a CAL for accessing a TFS server.